# Workflow - designer 2013 - email reminder not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, task-list, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I want to add a workflow to a task list, so it sends out an email reminder 2 and 3 months prior to due date.

this is the workflow I created, but it's not working, nothing is happening. What's wrong with it?

[image]

I don't know if this matters, but the task list is a part of a Teams site.

Any feedback is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you set "Variable: ReminderDate90" as "current item:due date" minus 3 months, in the loop, you check if "current item:due date" equals to "reminderdate90", it will never return true, so the action will not execute and your workflow don’t have action to add index for loop.

You can simple set the workflow as below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help, it still just sends out reminder for both of the variables, even though it's 3 months until due date, it also sends out the 2 month reminder.